Get issue <> component from JIRA REST API
We are trying to extract data from the Jira REST API for reporting, we use Components in Jira to mark our projects, in the data that we retrieve from the API I don't see anything like component_id through which you can connect components to specific issues, only project level.
I tried the endpoints for issues, fields, custom fields and components.
I already did some research and found that Hevo created there own table, so it must be possible
https://docs.hevodata.com/sources/engg-analytics/jira/#data-model
Also I found this about node association table, but there is no endpoint to get this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/sql-query-to-get-issue-components-from-jira-database-1353585654.html
Has anyone experience with this that might be able to help how and from which endpoint we can get the components connected to the issues?

How can I randomly select (choose) an item from a list (get a random element)?
It is done by JavaScript using MAth.random method.
example:
function getRandomItem(list) {
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
return list[randomIndex];
}
const myList = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape', 'watermelon'];
const randomItem = getRandomItem(myList);
console.log(randomItem);
